# Cannot deploy Firestore Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a simple function on Firebase Cloud Functions but console logs an error that I can't figure out where is

My index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.updateAccount = functions.firestore.document('accounts/{client_id}/movements').onWrite(change => {
    const document = change.after.exists ? change.after.data() : null
    console.log(document)
})
```

Console says:

```
⚠  functions: failed to create function updateAccount
HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors


Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        updateAccount


To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only functions:updateAccount


To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

Comment: If you're having a problem with the Firebase CLI showing unexpected errors, you should reach out to Firebase support directly.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your cloud function argument always points to the document level, not the collection level.

```
exports.updateAccount = functions.firestore
  .document('accounts/{client_id}/movements/{movement_id}')
  .onWrite(change => {
     const document = change.after.exists ? change.after.data() : null
     console.log(document)
})
```

You are trying to make the deployment in the collection level, not in the document level.

Comment: Hello, my path is something like, `Users/{UserID}/username` Users is collection, {UserID} is document and username is a field in the document. I am using a `onCreate()` trigger for the path mentioned above but getting the same error. I cannot use the path `Users/{UserID}/` because username field may not be existing when {UserID} document is created. username takes a few seconds to get updated so I need to use `onCreate()` on the field.

Comment: why you are mentioning the field name in function deployment ? You don't want to mention the field name,instead you just mention to the document being created as wild card like `Users/{UserID}`.The `UserID` is the reference to the document being created

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Your answer worked. But `username` field may take upto 10 seconds to get into the document. The document `{UserUID}` gets created way to early that my username field. So if I use `onCreate()` on the document name itself. It returns undefined 

Comment: Your point is the `username` field is taking some time to reflect back..?

Comment: Yes, thats taking time.The username field can take upto 10 seconds to update after the Dcoument is created. SO it  returns undefined to me.

Comment: No way,if it is like that ,it should be an `onUpdate` trigger,not an `onCreate` trigger

Comment: If I use `onUpdate()` then can I keep the path `Users/{UserID}/{username}` ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212470/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-pepe).

Comment: The path should be always to the document level,not to the collection level.Because changes are reflected to the document and not to the collection.It is very hard to say what is the exact problem without having code.So please post a new question